# Who are these guys in the end of every episode?

Tags: arakawa-under-the-bridge

At the end of every episode, there are some guys cosplaying the Chief and Hoshi

[image]

Who exactly are they?

Comment: I don't think they're anyone special. Must be ordinary actors for the live action after-credits omake.

Comment: but they should be mentioned on credit somewhere